# Angular 7 + Bootstrap 4 - typeahead

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to create dynamic reactive forms with bootstrap 4 typeahead completion. I would like to show the auto completion while focusing the text box. In my case I will be having multiple text box created by using reactive forms. Just gave a try and stuck with some issue. Can someone please help me to resolve the issue.

I have attached the sample code for reference:
[stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjjkwj-jvtjey)

Issue Screen shot:

[image]